# how to make uploaded file path in cake php plugins

Tags: cakephp

here 
[github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/](http://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload/)
i downloaded image upload plugin and it's working fine and shows success message and db it will show file name but 
image are not found in local root here i tryed to change but i can't find the path to change 
my folder app\webroot\profile_pic how to change this..

i changed in model

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'photo' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'profile_pic'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work

```
public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}profile_pic{DS}',
            'photo' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'photo_dir'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: could you provide path where your file was uploaded?

Comment: now uploaded in webroot\files\user\photo\4 but in my db field **photo_dir** was empty

Comment: I checked source code in github, and I realized tha I made few mistakes. Now should work :)

Comment: thanks for responding here  ` 'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}profile_pic{DS}'` code inserted but not saved in this location after removed imaged saved in previous dir and db updated with userid

Comment: Is it saving image directory in your photo_dir field ? I am facing problem,here image full directory not saving in database,it is saving only id.Upload working fine,but retrieve data directory not working fine.

Comment: @AlimonKarim your problem is propably in save method. (Something was messed up). Send on [gist](https://gist.github.com/) your save function